# How to call a Stored procedure with parameter from CTE (without cursor)

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a CTE that returns results and I want to call a stored procedure from the result of the CTE. Something like this:

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
  SELECT arg1, arg2, arg3 FROM ATable
)
EXEC dbo.A_StoredProcedure
  SELECT arg1 FROM MyCTE,
  SELECT arg2 FROM MyCTE,
  SELECT arg3 FROM MyCTE
```

This doesn't work of course because EXEC is not a command allowed directly after a CTE. I know that I can use a CURSOR to navigate and call my stored procedure, but since cursors are "evil" ;P ;P ;P ;P ;P I was wondering : is there a way to call my stored procedure from CTE result without a cursor?

if cursor is inevitable, how can I do it with a cursor?

Note : I would like if possible to not copy the content of my stored procedure into the CTE to simplify code maintenance.

Comment: May seem with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099913/pass-select-result-as-parameter-of-stored-procedure 

May you can try Table -Valued Parameters  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(SQL.100).aspx

Comment: You definitely can't use a stored procedure that way. Perhaps your stored procedure could be a [table valued function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) instead?

Comment: Yes Table Valued Parameters seems promising.

Comment: I cannot change the actual stored procedure, I could do a temporary stored procedure with table valued parameter.  But i would still need to do an operation for each row in the temporary stored procedure with the table valued Parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I continued my search and I found some answers that could be valid, but please feel free to comment and add other possible answers.

Answer 1 :
thanks to this article : [Execute stored procedure programmatically inside recursive CTE instead of Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582688/execute-stored-procedure-programmatically-inside-recursive-cte-instead-of-cursor)

Using a temp table could be possible, something like this :

```
DECLARE #TempEmp TABLE
(
   arg1 INT IDENTITY,
   arg2 INT,
   arg3 INT
)

INSERT INTO #TempTable
(
   arg1, arg2, arg3
)
SELECT arg1, arg2, arg3 FROM ATable

DECLARE @arg1 INT
DECLARE @arg2 INT
DECLARE @arg3 INT

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TempTable)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @arg1 = arg1, @arg2 = arg2, @arg3 = arg3 FROM #TempTable
    EXEC dbo.A_StoredProcedure @arg1, @arg2, @arg3

    DELETE FROM #TempTable WHERE arg1 = @arg1
END
```

Answer 2 :
thanks for this answer : [Cursor with Stored Procedure Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571804/cursor-with-stored-procedure-question).

If using a cursor, it could look like this :

```
DECLARE @arg1 INT
DECLARE @arg2 INT
DECLARE @arg3 INT

DECLARE cur CURSOR READ_ONLY
FOR 
    SELECT arg1, arg2, arg3 FROM ATable

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur
INTO @arg1, @arg2, @arg3

-- Boucle dans le résultat 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.A_StoredProcedure @arg1, @arg2, @arg3

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur 
    INTO @arg1, @arg2, @arg3
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Is there anyone that have other ideas?

Comment: Cursors are "EVIL" when doing row by row operations over a set of data when a set based statement would be optimal, however in this case the stored procedure is forcing the execution per row of `ATable` so the overhead of the cursor is negligible and I would say using a cursor is a sensible thing to do.

Comment: Thanks @EdwardComeau!